# 95% confidence interval for C-index after running elastic net for a cox model, and how to get net reclassification index

Tags: machine-learning, elastic-net

Can someone please show me how to get 95% confidence interval for c-index in the elastic net codes below:

```
############## Tuning of alpha -elastic net parameter###############

alphasOfInterest <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)  ## aplha=0 corresponds to ridge regression and alpha=1 is LASSO

cvs <- lapply(alphasOfInterest, function(curAlpha) {
## column 1 & 2 are time and status

  cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(dat_cv[,-c(1,2)]),y = as.matrix(dat_cv[,c(1,2)]) , alpha = curAlpha, family = "cox",nfolds=10)
})

optimumPerAlpha <- sapply(seq_along(alphasOfInterest), function(curi) {
  curcvs <- cvs[[curi]]
  curAlpha <- alphasOfInterest[curi]
  indOfMin <- match(curcvs$lambda.min, curcvs$lambda)
  c(lam = curcvs$lambda.min, alph = curAlpha, cvup = curcvs$cvm[indOfMin])
})

posOfOptimum <- which.min(optimumPerAlpha["cvup", ])
overall.lambda.min <- optimumPerAlpha["lam", posOfOptimum]
overall.alpha.min <- optimumPerAlpha["alph", posOfOptimum] ### optimum value of alpha
overall.criterionthreshold <- optimumPerAlpha["cvup", posOfOptimum]

foldid=sample(rep(seq(10),length=nrow(dat_cv)))

for (i in 1:10){

  sample_index<-which(foldid==i)

  dat_train<-dat_cv[-sample_index,]
  dat_test<-dat_cv[sample_index,]

  model.cv<-cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(dat_train[,-c(1:2)]),y=as.matrix(dat_train[,c(1:2)]),nfolds = 10,family="cox",alpha=overall.alpha.min)

  pred = predict(model.cv, newx = as.matrix(dat_test[,-c(1:2)]),s='lambda.min')

  cindex[i]<-apply(pred, 2, Cindex, y=as.matrix(dat_test[,c(1:2)]))

  models[[i]]<-model.cv

cvmodel<-models

# Recursive function for merging data frames based on a common column
require(glmnet)

dataFrames<-list()

#cvmodel<-readRDS("H:/Work/VACS/Final_results_0702/BEModel/Models_ResultCVenet_BE450Epic_combined.RDS")

for(i in 1:length(cvmodel)){

  impvar<-coef(cvmodel[[i]],s=cvmodel[[i]]$lambda.min) ## extract coefficients for minimum lambda

  impvar<-data.frame(as.matrix(impvar[impvar[,1]!=0,]))

  colnames(impvar)[1]<-paste0("coef","_model",i)

  impvar$var<-rownames(impvar)

  dataFrames[[i]]<-impvar

}

recursiveMerge <- function(dataFrames, commonColumn) {
  # Base case: If only one data frame remains, return it
  if (length(dataFrames) == 1) {
    return(dataFrames[[1]])
  }

  # Merge the first two data frames
  merged <- merge(dataFrames[[1]], dataFrames[[2]], by = commonColumn, all = TRUE)

  # Remove the merged data frames from the list
  dataFrames <- dataFrames[-c(1, 2)]

  # Append the merged data frame to the remaining data frames
  dataFrames <- c(dataFrames, list(merged))

  # Recursively call the function with the updated data frames
  recursiveMerge(dataFrames, commonColumn)
}

# Example usage
# Suppose we have three data frames with a common column "ID"


commonColumn<-"var"

# Call the recursive merge function
mergedData <- recursiveMerge(dataFrames, commonColumn)

mergedData$na_counts <- rowSums(is.na(mergedData))

mergedData$pro_score<-(10-mergedData$na_counts)/10

# Output the merged data frame
print(mergedData)

write.csv(mergedData,"impvar.csv")
```